# Displaying GeoJSON data

Tags: openlayers, geojson, coordinate-system

I'm trying to display a polygon over a city using GeoJSON, I validated the file using http://www.mapshaper.org/ and the polygon displays just fine, but when I try to display this layer over an OpenStreetMap (OSM) layer I don't see anything.

This is my code:

```
var data = '{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2039" } }, "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 179029.98345868432, 667951.77896603046 ], [ 179242.5448687863, 667376.61279751919 ], [ 179417.59544181143, 667201.56222449406 ], [ 181343.15174508799, 667551.66337054444 ], [ 181718.26011585613, 667714.21033121063 ], [ 181418.17341924162, 666526.36715711141 ], [ 181243.12284621646, 665576.09261783212 ], [ 181155.59755970389, 665288.50953357643 ], [ 181443.18064395949, 665025.93367403874 ], [ 181280.63368329327, 664375.74583137396 ], [ 181118.08672262708, 663713.05437635025 ], [ 181193.10839678071, 663400.4640673768 ], [ 181405.66980688268, 663450.47851681255 ], [ 181555.71315518994, 663412.96767973574 ], [ 181768.27456529188, 663200.40626963368 ], [ 182043.35403718855, 662962.83763481386 ], [ 181893.31068888129, 662662.75093819934 ], [ 182468.47685739247, 662212.62089327758 ], [ 182518.49130682822, 661349.87164051086 ], [ 182455.97324503353, 660874.7343708711 ], [ 181843.29623944554, 659786.92009564349 ], [ 180242.83385750139, 660949.75604502473 ], [ 179830.21464965641, 661387.38247758767 ], [ 179205.03403170948, 660537.13683717977 ], [ 178042.19808232816, 660424.60432594933 ], [ 177767.11861043153, 660599.65489897446 ], [ 177166.94521720248, 660537.13683717977 ], [ 176604.28266105024, 660524.63322482083 ], [ 176144.77490685924, 660612.15851133352 ], [ 176032.2423956288, 660887.23798323015 ], [ 176107.26406978242, 661549.92943825398 ], [ 176344.83270460228, 662362.66424158495 ], [ 176894.99164839557, 662725.26899999415 ], [ 177170.07112029221, 662837.80151122459 ], [ 177482.66142926569, 663162.89543255698 ], [ 177545.17949106038, 663738.06160106824 ], [ 177557.68310341932, 664000.63746060594 ], [ 177732.73367644445, 664113.16997183638 ], [ 178207.87094608412, 665701.12874142162 ], [ 178020.31676070005, 665876.17931444675 ], [ 177982.80592362324, 666151.25878634339 ], [ 178370.41790675034, 666126.25156162551 ], [ 178570.47570449335, 667101.53332562267 ], [ 178958.08768762046, 667826.74284244119 ], [ 179029.98345868432, 667951.77896603046 ] ] ] } } ] }';
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                object: data,
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        })
    ]
});
var telAviv = ol.proj.transform([34.81185, 32.04314], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
map.setView(
    new ol.View({
        center: telAviv,
        zoom: 10
    })
);
```

Please notice the coordinates the client supplied me, I'm not sure how to project them onto the map over Tel Aviv city.

I'm using OpenLayers version 3.16.0.

Link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zykr2t0x/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that works (I hope its correct also): https://plnkr.co/edit/2PG4KhH29pv9n2ZHpjvT?p=preview

Notice: you have to define your projection in index.html with proj4.js.

Edit: I have just seen that you are using different version of OpenLayers3. I think it might work with that one also, try changing this version to yours and see if it does.